# Why the write function does not print the 'asd' integer variable?

Tags: c, pointers, reference, dereference

I'm currently learning pointers and the `write` function. I've written the code below. My question is the `write` functions does not print anything at all. In the `write` function's manual, it says that the second parameter must be buffer so is a pointer to that value. I put the `asd`'s address through the `pAsd` pointer. In according to function's manual, it should print the value of `asd` but it doesn't.

```c
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int  asd  = 21;
    int *pAsd = &asd;

    write(1, pAsd, 4);
}
```

Comment: What is your evidence that it doesn't print what you expected?

Comment: Depending on byte-order, you write three zeroes followed by the (binary) value `00010101`. Or the binary value `00010101` followed by three zeroes. The `write` function doesn't write characters, it writes raw data directly as it's stored in memory. So it's writing what it is defined to write, but just not what you seemingly expect.

Comment: You're printing the bytes of the number  `21` as if they're characters.

Comment: `21` is a control character, what are you expecting to see?

Comment: When you use `write` to write raw bytes, you have to think really carefully about what those raw bytes actually are.  You might have expected to write bytes with values `0x32` and `0x31`, which are the ASCII codes for the characters `2` and `1` that make up a human-readable decimal representation of the number 21.  But that's not what the code you've got does.

Comment: For comparison, try `write(1, "Hello, world!\n", 14);`.  Or for another comparison, try `write(1, "21", 2);`.

Comment: Also, if you're on a Linux system, learn about the `hd` program, which shows you the contents of a file both as hexadecimal byte values, and as human-readable printing characters.

Comment: thank you for comments. I've totally forgot how integer values stored in the memory. And now I know what write function does exactly, thanks. Also, @SteveSummit thank you for your suggestion. I'll look at.

Comment: @HuseyinDonmez glad you learned something instead of getting frustrated!